# Reputation icon in (old) top bar shows +2 while +10 was earned

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

I religiously click all tabs in my profile to clear any counter every time I use the site. You won't see "[500] reputation" or "[42] responses" in my profile when I take a screenshot of it.

As far as I know, the reputation icon in the top bar shows your net change in reputation since your last visit of the reputation tab (as long as the net change is positive).

This morning, upon my first visit, the reputation icon in the top bar (the old one, not the new one currently being tested) showed "+2" (wish I had taken a screenshot). Curious as to why that happened, I clicked it, and saw the correct +10, equal to the change on my reputation tab:

[image: +10]

My https://stackoverflow.com/reputation overview also shows nothing that explains this:

```
 3  41830638 (-1)
 2  41830493 (10)
 2  41830493 (10)
 3  41830785 (-1)
-- 2017-01-24 rep +175  = 81139     
 2  41825402 (10)
```

So what happened here? Why does the reputation change in the top bar not match the reputation change in my profile?

Maybe someone downvoted four of my questions and/or answers, and reverted it themselves, but the reputation change was cached somewhere?

2017-02-08: and again. The top bar showed +6 while I earned +10 and didn't lose anything on any other site as far as I cal tell.

After downvoting three answers after this, the reputation tab now showed "-5":

[image: -5]

This makes so little sense to me. What's going wrong with these calculations, or what am I missing?

Maybe it's because two other answers I downvoted got deleted?

Meh, must be it: [Reputation tab shows wrong change if downvoted answers were removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128310/reputation-tab-shows-wrong-change-if-downvoted-answers-were-removed)

Comment: Maybe because you were down voted on Software Engineering.se or any of your other communities

Comment: Good point Rene, but apart from an [accept/unaccept at SE on Jan 17](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/35973/codecaster?tab=reputation) I could not find any recent negative reputation changes.

Comment: I didn't want to go with blame caching so this was my second best shot ...

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: *"I religiously click all tabs in my profile to clear any counter every time I use the site."* They have medication that will help with that.

Comment: @CodyGray: Yes, but can you click the medication?

Comment: I know you might not really care, but you do realize you're revealing downvotes on two specific posts, yeah?

Comment: @Mike I didn't really realise that, but they're preserved in the history of this post if I edit them, so now it doesn't matter anymore. :)

Comment: I'm going to go tell both of those users right now! Seriously, though, quick edit, delete these comments, and (probably) no one else will suspect. Up to you.

Comment: @rene: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2013/03/29/il-a-bon-dos-le-cache/